# When I mark an e-mail as "Not junk" in MS Outlook, does this in any way get communicated to Gmail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, spam-prevention

I use Gmail's servers, and Outlook (Windows) as my mail client.

I occasionally get false positives identified as SPAM, requiring me to check my Spam folder regularly. When I see a legitimate e-mail in there, I always try to mark it as "Not junk" within the Outlook client, in the hope that this somehow has an action of "teaching" the junk identifying algorithm. It also has the effect of moving the message straight to the Inbox.

But does this actually have any lasting effect? Does Outlook actually pass the "not junk" identifier to Gmail? Is anything actually **learned**? If not, then what local effect does the action have. Because if nothing, then I may as well just move the messages to my Inbox directly.

Answer (score 0):

According to my extensive search, I didn't find any official documents which introduces the principle of spam filtering. And for the impact of spam filtering on Gmail server, there seems to be no accurate explanation.

Considering your needs, it is recommended that you could select the trusted spam in the Junk folder and click on the Report Message option and choose Not Junk, which may have an impact on your spam filtering.

[image]

If you trust spam from the same sender or from the same domain, it's suggested that you could try to add this sender or domain to a safe sender to reduce the inconvenience of manually moving it to your inbox. If you think there are too many trusted messages in your Spam folder, you can also try to change the level of protection in the Junk Email Filter.

For more information, please refer to:

[Add recipients of my email messages to the Safe Senders List - Outlook (microsoft.com)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-recipients-of-my-email-messages-to-the-safe-senders-list-be1baea0-beab-4a30-b968-9004332336ce)

[Change the level of protection in the Junk Email Filter - Outlook (microsoft.com)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-level-of-protection-in-the-junk-email-filter-e89c12d8-9d61-4320-8c57-d982c8d52f6b)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something definitive. "No accurate explanation" is what I came up with too.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed little official document explaining how that works. So, I prefer to use the report message add in to report the misidentified spam mentioned above.